# Copy content without folder source

Tags: javascript, webpack

in the webpack conf i try to configure the CopyPlugin for the minified files, but i encounter a problem, when the minified files are copied to the output folder, its copied with the src folder, how can i only copy the files in the output folder without copying the src folder?

Below i will show how i made the copy script.

```
new CopyPlugin({
    patterns: [
        {
            from: "./src/*.html",
            to: path.resolve(__dirname + "/output")
        }
    ]
})
```

Comment: You can use the option `context`

Comment: That was it :D Thanks for the reply @jabaa